# How do I cite a range of lines?

Tags: cross-referencing, memoir, line-numbering

I want to be able to specify a short excerpt of text that can be cited as a range of lines in the output PDF, ideally with this kind of syntax:

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{lineno}

\begin{document}
    \runninglinenumbers*
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam lacinia posuere
    magna ut imperdiet. \labellines{nunc-pellentesque}{Nunc pellentesque} velit quis
    leo interdum ullamcorper. Ut fringilla sapien ut sem viverra, et rhoncus enim
    lobortis. Morbi diam eros, tristique nec feugiat eu, consequat ac dui. Duis
    molestie, sem id efficitur dignissim, velit metus auctor orci, sit amet mattis
    metus purus in nibh. Etiam mattis, magna ut imperdiet molestie, ex leo viverra
    velit, ac posuere augue est maximus risus. Etiam ac pellentesque nulla. Morbi
    quis pharetra purus. Proin porta, turpis et scelerisque hendrerit, elit eros
    malesuada mi, a imperdiet massa est id nibh. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad
    litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos.
    \labellines{nunc-pharetra}{Nunc pharetra vehicula metus, eu tincidunt arcu
        aliquet et. Aenean ac odio nunc. Etiam ultricies purus non dolor tincidunt, et
        ultricies turpis consequat. Integer vitae ullamcorper eros. Nullam pulvinar
        dictum nunc. Morbi ac justo mi.}

    % \reflines{nunc-pellentesque} should print "line 2"
    ``Nunc pellentesque\ldots'' was on \reflines{nunc-pellentesque}.

    % \reflines{nunc-pharetra} should print "lines 10--13"
    ``Nunc pharetra\ldots'' was on \reflines{nunc-pharetra}.
\end{document}
```

The text all by itself looks like this:

[image: pdf output without those commands]

Comment: Are `\labellines` etc. valid commands? Or your imagination how those commands should be called?

Comment: @ChristianHupfer, they're imagined commands for doing what I hope to do.

Comment: I'll think about it -- it requires an start- and end-linenumber storage however

Comment: @ChristianHupfer, my feeling was that you could do this with some slight modifications to `smartref`...

Comment: `smartref`?  What is `smartref`?

Comment: @ChristianHupfer, it's [a package](http://ctan.mirrors.hoobly.com/macros/latex/contrib/smartref/smartref-doc.pdf) that can process reference ranges.

Comment: I don't know that package -- and I **can't** see that `smartref` is mentioned anywhere in your question before!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An easy solution, but perhaps not failsafe:

- Place a `\linelabel{start:#1}` at the begin of the enclosed #2
- Place a `\linelabel{end:#1}` at the end of the enclosed #2

Use `\getrefnumber` from `refcount` package and extract the line numbers. In principle `\lineref` would do, but this does not yield expandable numbers, so the comparison will fail.

I did not add code to check whether the label exists at all!

---

```
\documentclass{memoir}


\usepackage{refcount}
\usepackage{lineno}

\newcommand{\labellines}[2]{%
  \linelabel{start:#1}%
  #2%
  \linelabel{end:#1}%
}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\reflines}[1]{%
  \begingroup
  \edef\temp@a{\getrefnumber{start:#1}}%
  \edef\temp@b{\getrefnumber{end:#1}}%
  \ifnum\temp@a = \temp@b
  line \temp@a%
  \else
  lines \temp@a\ and \temp@b%
  \fi
  \endgroup
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
    \runninglinenumbers*
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam lacinia posuere
    magna ut imperdiet. \labellines{nunc-pellentesque}{Nunc pellentesque} velit quis
    leo interdum ullamcorper. Ut fringilla sapien ut sem viverra, et rhoncus enim
    lobortis. Morbi diam eros, tristique nec feugiat eu, consequat ac dui. Duis
    molestie, sem id efficitur dignissim, velit metus auctor orci, sit amet mattis
    metus purus in nibh. Etiam mattis, magna ut imperdiet molestie, ex leo viverra
    velit, ac posuere augue est maximus risus. Etiam ac pellentesque nulla. Morbi
    quis pharetra purus. Proin porta, turpis et scelerisque hendrerit, elit eros
    malesuada mi, a imperdiet massa est id nibh. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad
    litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos.
    \labellines{nunc-pharetra}{Nunc pharetra vehicula metus, eu tincidunt arcu
        aliquet et. Aenean ac odio nunc. Etiam ultricies purus non dolor tincidunt, et
        ultricies turpis consequat. Integer vitae ullamcorper eros. Nullam pulvinar
        dictum nunc. Morbi ac justo mi.}

    % \reflines{nunc-pellentesque} should print "line 2"
    ``Nunc pellentesque\ldots'' was on \reflines{nunc-pellentesque}.

    % \reflines{nunc-pharetra} should print "lines 10--13"
    ``Nunc pharetra\ldots'' was on \reflines{nunc-pharetra}.
\end{document}
```

[image]