# Expansion rules for csname/endcsname inside \edef

Tags: macros, csname

I am aware of this response

[Why does \def fail inside \edef?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/258660/why-does-def-fail-inside-edef)

which explains that `\def` is unexpandable, and hence subsequent uses of the attempted definitions fail inside an `\edef`.

I would like to understand why all of the following work as expected:

```
\edef\x{\expandafter\def\csname y\endcsname{1}\y}
\edef\x{\expandafter\edef\csname y\endcsname{1}\y}
\edef\x{\expandafter\let\csname y\endcsname=1\y}
```

### EDIT

All of the above work correctly when used alone. In particular,

```
\edef\x{\expandafter\def\csname y\endcsname{1}\y}

\x

\edef\x{\expandafter\edef\csname z\endcsname{2}\z}

\x

\edef\x{\expandafter\let\csname w\endcsname=3\w}

\x
```

will produce

```
1
2
3
```

but

```
\edef\x{\expandafter\def\csname y\endcsname{1}\y}

\x

\edef\x{\expandafter\edef\csname y\endcsname{2}\y}

\x   % where the error appears.

\edef\x{\expandafter\let\csname y\endcsname=3\y}

\x
```

produces the error

```
! Missing control sequence inserted.
<inserted text> 
                \inaccessible 
l.33 \x
```

Comment: `\csname whatever\endcsname` expands to `\whatever`. If the command is not defined, `\whatever` is exactly the same as `\relax`, so in your case after getting `\y` it doesn't expand further. So you are defining `\x` three times, first with meaning `\def\y{1}\y`, second with `\edef\y{1}\y`, and third with `\let\y=1\y`. The problem would be if you actually executed those definition by letting `\x` expand, in which case `\y` would be defined after the first use so the second definition of `\x` would be like `\edef1{1}1` and when executing `\x` again it would raise errors.

Comment: @Manuel Your comment should be an answer

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Please see the updated question.

Comment: In the second case you need to jump over the initial `\edef\x` too

Comment: I guess my question is what is the difference between `\edef\x{\edef\y{1}\y}` and the version that uses `\csname`...

Comment: @Manuel I am not sure I understand how you get `\edef1{1}`. How does the use of `\csname` cause that, when `\def\y{1}` does not cause a subsequent re-definition to expand to `\edef1{1}`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`\csname` is expandable, which means that it will do its action in an `\edef`. The action is to build a control sequence token from the tokens it finds up to the matching `\endcsname`, performing full expansion as it goes.

Once the action of `\csname` ends, the token gets expanded or not according to the context; it will, in `\edef`, provided it is expandable. If it is not expandable, `\edef` will simply store it in the replacement text it is building and go on to the next token.

Thus the problem is: what token results from `\csname y\endcsname`? Obviously `\y`, but now its expandability depends on the meaning `\y` has.

There are two cases:

- `\y` has no previous meaning (that is, it is undefined);
- `\y` is already known to TeX.

There are several methods to assign a meaning to a control sequence token: `\y` can be

1. a macro (defined with `\def`, `\edef`, `\gdef` or `\xdef`);
2. a primitive;
3. a `\countdef`, `\dimendef`, `\skipdef`, `\muskipdef`, `\toksdef`, `\chardef`, or `\mathchardef` token;
4. a font selector (defined with `\font`);
5. a token defined with `\let`.

In case 1 `\y` is expandable; in case 2 it can be or not, depending on the primitive (for instance `\if`, `\the`, `\csname` are expandable, `\relax` is not). In cases 3 and 4 `\y` is not expandable. In case 5, `\y` inherits the expandability (and definedness) from the token it is `\let` to.

However, there is a *big* difference between

```
\edef\x{... \y ...}
```

and

```
\edef\x{... \csname y\endcsname ...}
```

when `\y` has no previous meaning. When a token is built with `\csname`, if it is unknown, TeX will *always* assign it the same meaning as `\relax` (such an assignment is local).

Consider your `\edef\x{\expandafter\def\csname y\endcsname{1}\y}`, which is the same as `\edef\x{\def\csname y\endcsname{1}\y}` (because `\def` is not expandable). Assuming `\y` has no previous definition, the built token is equivalent to `\relax`. Indeed, if you add `\show\x` you will be answered

```
> \x=macro:
->\def \y {1}\y .
```

Now if you *execute* `\x`, `\y` will be defined as a macro expanding to `1`. A further `\edef\x{\def\csname y\endcsname{1}\y}` followed by `\show\x` will print

```
> \x=macro:
->\def 1{1}1.
```

Note that the built token *has been* expanded, because now `\y` is a macro.

Still no error will be raised, because TeX has simply stored the definition. But if we try to execute `\x`, we get

```
! Missing control sequence inserted.
<inserted text> 
                \inaccessible 
<to be read again> 
                   1
\x ->\def 1
           {1}1
```

because `\def 1` is illegal.

Your “working” example does not raise errors because `\y`, `\z` and `\w` are undefined tokens when `\edef\x{...}` is performed.

For completeness, what happens when you do `\edef\x{... \y ...}` and `\y` is undefined? You of course get an error of `Undefined control sequence` when the `\edef` is being carried out.